# Parse through related tags in HTML

Tags: regex, powershell

I need to extract item-name, item-manufacturer, item-actual from below `outerHTML` in Powershell.

```
<DIV class=row>
<DIV class="col-sm-5 col-xs-8"><A class=item-name href="/details/drugs/39467/spasmonil-20mg">Spasmonil (20mg)</A>
    <DIV class=text-small>2 ml</DIV>
    <DIV class="item-manufacturer visible-xs">Cipla Limited</DIV></DIV>
    <DIV class="col-sm-5 hidden-xs"><SPAN class=item-manufacturer>Cipla Limited</SPAN></DIV>
    <DIV class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-right">
    <DIV class=item-actual>Rs. 6</DIV>
    <DIV class=item-price>Rs. 6</DIV></DIV></DIV></LI>
    <LI class="list-item item js-drug">
    <DIV class=row>
    <DIV class="col-sm-5 col-xs-8"><A class=item-name href="/details/drugs/40759/sprintas-75mg">Sprintas (75mg)</A>
    <DIV class=text-small>28 Tablets</DIV>
    <DIV class="item-manufacturer visible-xs">Intas Laboratories Pvt Ltd</DIV></DIV>
    <DIV class="col-sm-5 hidden-xs"><SPAN class=item-manufacturer>Intas Laboratories Pvt Ltd</SPAN></DIV>
    <DIV class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-right">
    <DIV class=item-actual>Rs. 5.72</DIV>
    <DIV class=item-price>Rs. 5.72</DIV></DIV></DIV></LI>
    <LI class="list-item item js-drug">
```

Rendered output looks like this:

```
Spasmonil (20mg) - Cipla Limited - Rs. 6
Sprintas (75mg) - Intas Laboratories Pvt - Rs. 5.72
```

I am doing it in quite in-efficient way and I get 4 outputs (drugsname, drugsquan, drugspric, drugsmanu) in different txt files and I manually combine it afterwards. Can someone help me in doing it in some elegant way.

```
$regex1 = 'item-name.*?>(.*?)</A>'
$regex2 = 'text-small>(.*?)</DIV>'
$regex3 ='"item-manufacturer visible-xs">(.*?)</DIV>'
$regex4 ='item-actual>(.*?)</DIV>'

$drugsname = $ie.Document.body.outerHTML -split "`r`n" | 
  ForEach-Object{
    If($_ -match $regex1){
      $matches[1]      
    }
  }

$drugsquan = $ie.Document.body.outerHTML  -split "`r`n" | 
  ForEach-Object{
    If($_ -match $regex2){
      $matches[1]      
    }
  }

$drugsmanu = $ie.Document.body.outerHTML  -split "`r`n" | 
  ForEach-Object{
    If($_ -match $regex3){
      $matches[1]      
    }
  }

$drugspric = $ie.Document.body.outerHTML  -split "`r`n" | 
  ForEach-Object{
    If($_ -match $regex4){
      $matches[1]      
    }
  }

$drugsname > "d:\users\desktop\HKD\($control)drugsname.txt"
$drugsquan > "d:\users\desktop\HKD\($control)drugsquan.txt"
$drugsmanu > "d:\users\desktop\HKD\($control)drugsmanu.txt"
$drugspric > "d:\users\desktop\HKD\($control)drugspric.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. If we do not use Regex to parse HTML, then what should be used ?

Comment: you could Interpret the Input as XML: [xml]$data = $contentFromWeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a multi-line/single-line regex in a here-string (aka "jumbo shrimp in a can"):

```
$data = 
@'
<DIV class=row>
<DIV class="col-sm-5 col-xs-8"><A class=item-name href="/details/drugs/39467/spasmonil-20mg">Spasmonil (20mg)</A>
    <DIV class=text-small>2 ml</DIV>
    <DIV class="item-manufacturer visible-xs">Cipla Limited</DIV></DIV>
    <DIV class="col-sm-5 hidden-xs"><SPAN class=item-manufacturer>Cipla Limited</SPAN></DIV>
    <DIV class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-right">
    <DIV class=item-actual>Rs. 6</DIV>
    <DIV class=item-price>Rs. 6</DIV></DIV></DIV></LI>
    <LI class="list-item item js-drug">
    <DIV class=row>
    <DIV class="col-sm-5 col-xs-8"><A class=item-name href="/details/drugs/40759/sprintas-75mg">Sprintas (75mg)</A>
    <DIV class=text-small>28 Tablets</DIV>
    <DIV class="item-manufacturer visible-xs">Intas Laboratories Pvt Ltd</DIV></DIV>
    <DIV class="col-sm-5 hidden-xs"><SPAN class=item-manufacturer>Intas Laboratories Pvt Ltd</SPAN></DIV>
    <DIV class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 text-right">
    <DIV class=item-actual>Rs. 5.72</DIV>
    <DIV class=item-price>Rs. 5.72</DIV></DIV></DIV></LI>
    <LI class="list-item item js-drug">
'@

[regex]$regex = 
@'
(?ms).*?<DIV class=row>.*?
.+?item-name href=".+?>(.+?)</A>.*?
.+?text-small>(.+?)</DIV>.*?
.+?item-manufacturer.+?>(.+?)</DIV></DIV>.*?
.+?item-actual>(.+?)</DIV>
'@

$regex.Matches($data) |
foreach {
          [PSCustomObject]@{
          Name = $_.Groups[1].value
          Quantity = $_.Groups[2].Value
          Manufacturer = $_.Groups[3].Value
          Price = $_.Groups[4].Value
        }
}

Name                       Quantity                   Manufacturer               Price                    
----                       --------                   ------------               -----                    
Spasmonil (20mg)           2 ml                       Cipla Limited              Rs. 6                    
Sprintas (75mg)            28 Tablets                 Intas Laboratories Pvt Ltd Rs. 5.72
```

Now you have an object collection you can sort, filter, format and export to suit your needs.

Comment: This is really brillant, so I removed my answer. Yours gets my vote.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for being naive but I need something like this : $data=@'get-content $ie.Document.body.outerHTML'. Since all of above HTML data is passed onto my program in $ie.Document.body.outerHTML. Can you please advise how can I change the "$data="

Comment: @MickyBalladelli - Thanks! Yogesh - It's made to work with all the data (multiple rows) as a single, multi-line string.  It should consume $ie.Document.body.outerHTML without modification - just substitute that for $data.  If it's in a file, use Get-Content -Raw to read the file as a single multi-line string.